# Av input Citroen c5 break

Tags: audio, citroen

[image]

So I have found this av input in my Citroen c5 break 2.0 vtr in the glove compartment.

I fail to find in the manual what it is for and google is not being much help either.

Does anyone know what it is for and if I can connect my phone to it.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Can't guarantee this, but those are rca sockets and the red & white ones are for audio, the yellow for video.

This will depend on what equipment you have in the car - rear headrest screens possibly, but the audio may play through the car sound system - you can get a 3.5mm jack to rca cable easily or a friend may even have one and test that part...